# what is the difference between a software engineer and project manager?

Tags: project-management, computer-science, software

I understand that a software engineers job is to work with all aspects of developing and supporting a software system. How does a project manager fit/work with a software engineer in a small team (5 or less) environment?

Comment: One might just as well ask what is the difference between pig and a chicken.  The two roles are completely different, requiring almost no skills in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat -- job descriptions and the duties attached vary wildly from company to company and even department to department.

A Project Manager:-

- Manages the project schedule.
- Manages the project budget and other resources
- Communicates progress to the business and upper management
- Allocates resources within the team
- resolves disputes between team members

A Software Engineer:-

- obtains and manages a list of business requirements.
- selects suitable technologies to use for the solution.
- produces an outline solution (hopefully based on use cases or similar)
- provides the project manager with time and resource requirements for the above
- develops a testing strategy
- tracks and manages defects and fixes
- constantly cross references the solution, defects etc. back to the business requirements.

Most people with the "Software Engineer" job title do a considerable amount of programming (I know I did), but, programming is not really what it is about.